# Onclick for tab not working

Tags: html, tabs

This is what I have in my layout view. Home tab and To Do tab.

[image]

And codes in my html:

```
<div id="tabs">

<ul>
    <li id="li_tab1" onclick="HomeTab"><a>Home</a></li>
    <li id="li_tab2" onclick="ToDoTab"><a>To Do</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="Content_Area">
    <div id="HomeTab">
        <p>Home tab content goes here.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="ToDoTab" style="display: none;">
    <p>To Do tab content goes here.</p>
```

The problem here is I tried to click on the To Do tab but it seems that the onclick is not working. Please help! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> //use this code istead of that..

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tabs">

<ul>
<li id="li_tab1"><a href="#HomeTab">Home</a></li>
<li id="li_tab2"><a href="#ToDoTab">To Do</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="Content_Area">
<div id="HomeTab">
<p>Home tab content goes here.</p>
</div>

<div id="ToDoTab" style="display: none;">
<p>To Do tab content goes here.</p></div
```

> Use this code it will work
>   Use this javascript it will work to hide the content

```
<script type="text/javascript">


var showcont = [];
var showcont_containers = [];
 $('#tabs ul li a').each(function () {
  // note that this only compares the pathname, not the entire url
  // which actually may be required for a more terse solution.
    if (this.pathname == window.location.pathname) {
        showcont.push(this);
        showcont_containers.push($(this.hash).get(0));
    };
});


$(showcont).click(function(){

       $(showcont_containers).hide().filter(this.hash).fadeIn();

});

</script>
```

Comment: When i edited and took out the style code for ToDoTab i can see the content when i clicked on to do tab. but at the same time at home tab i can see content for both home tab and to do tab.

Comment: but i'm using razor view, where should i insert the java script? sorry i'm really new to this.

Comment: you copy and paste the code in your file..you will get.. i know it will work with razor view also..try it..

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery UI:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    });
</script>

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>Content of Tab 1</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>Content of Tab 2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Check out [this](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) link for more information